# How do i pass properties from ANT to jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, ant

Im running the ant script in job1, it will ultimately do the build and deployment process. once its process done, it will initiate the next job (ie. job2). How can i make the bridge between the job1 and job2?

Job 1 : It wil give the input to the next job(inputs are in the form of ant properties)
Job 2 : It should receive the input from job1 and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the job1 go to "add post build action" the select "trigger parameterized build on other project" .

in the section "Project to build" give you job2 name
click on "add parameter" and pass parameter to job2

for eg:
job2_ANT_PATH=$job1_ANT_PATH

then in the job2 configuration, select the "This build is parameterized" build, and add parameter as a string parameter and give the variable name same as you have assigned in the job1. i.e job2_ANT_PATH